# permissions in IIS for asp.net local website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-7

Hi guys i want to create a website[local] and one of its abilities must be taking screenshot from desktop (desktop of pc where IIS is running, totally i mean server side desktop), you should say why serverside , answer is , i want to see my desktop from my mobile device when im downstairs to see if downloads are finished or not :D

I use this code in asp.net page in codebehind

```
    int screenLeft = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left;
    int screenTop = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top;
    int screenWidth = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
    int screenHeight = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;

    // Create a bitmap of the appropriate size to receive the screenshot.
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight))
    {
        // Draw the screenshot into our bitmap.
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(screenLeft, screenTop, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
        }

        // Do something with the Bitmap here, like save it to a file:
        MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        bmp.Dispose();
        IMG.Src = &quot;data:image/jpg;base64,&quot; +     Convert.ToBase64String(ms2.GetBuffer());
        ms2.Dispose();
    }
```

when running from visual studio , its ok , it takes screen shots, but when i published website to local host its showing this error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The handle is invalid

**Description :** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The handle is invalid

**Source Error :**

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace :**

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The handle is invalid]
>      System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation) +781
>      System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize) +35
>      ScreenShot.capture_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +334
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +154
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3707

Any idea what to do???????  i am feeling its about permissions but how to set them , i donno...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys i found a way to solve this issue, i downloaded IIS 8.0 express from MS website and after setting its applicationhost.config for my website path and binding ip-port and giving firewall permissions to it , now i can take screenshot of my desktop :D
thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction was to say, it's not possible, but since you managed to do that in VS, may be it is..

To setup the user, in the IIS you need to go to Application Pools -> right click on the application pool that your site is using (by default it's ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated) -> Advanced settings -> find the setting called Identity, click on the [...] and then in the new popup click the radio button Custom account, and set your user account there.

If that doesn't solve the problem, I don't think anything will

Comment: hi and thanks to response , it uses DefaultAppPool , so what should i do with username and password?????? i mean what should i set , i mean i have to set my windows authentication info or sth else or any thing i want!!  after that what should i do with my codebehind, is there a place to enter these username and password in codebehind???

Comment: in that case I'm inclined to say it's not possible to accomplish your goal. try to create another console application that you can start and that can capture the desktop, save it to a location that your web process can read from, and then return that image.

Comment: i actually tried that way too, there is no error BUT there is no result too. i mean app runs i can see it in resource monitor, but never ends , so my page never work, and image never created. i saved my image on second drive and there is no need permissions to write on that drive , and one more thnig this app works just fine on windows 8 IIS...

Comment: one more thing console app ends with no result , and win-app never ends

Comment: I'm afraid that's all I can think of.. may be it would be easier just to use an remote app like TeamViewer, it's free and has app for android, iphone and windows phone

Comment: i added line by line log text and got sth, in console app in line: g.CopyFromScreen(screenLeft, screenTop, 0, 0, bmp.Size);  it throws exception "The handle is invalid" !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: My take on this is that when using IIS Express from Visual Studio it runs as a user process with access to the desktop and can take a screenshot. However proper IIS runs as a service without an interactive desktop and so taking a screenshot fails. There are better ways to find out whether a download has finished

Comment: ook and is there any way to fix this matter, Peter Hahndorf??????  cause its just a part of my app, it contains many parts such as filemanager cmd webcam controller and ... and i have to fix this.