# VS ISSExpress can take screenshot, but normal IIS can't

Tags: iis

So this is a copy of this thread:

[permissions in IIS for asp.net local website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727858/permissions-in-iis-for-asp-net-local-website)

I'm making this post rather than necroing that one, as it is apparently "solved".
But the guy didn't mention in much detail how he managed to achieve it. I am in the exact same situation. Except I am running a wcf service. The main code that fails is the following:

Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screen as Image);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, screen.Size);

My understanding is that VS IISExpress is run as a normal application, and the regular IIS isn't. I've changed my application pool to run as my own user account but no luck. Anyone know what this guy means?

Comment: Your understanding is too shallow. IIS/web apps have no access to a user's desktop due to session isolation https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ So of course you won't get the screenshots you wanted. That guy in the thread you linked clearly uses IIS Express at last.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [permissions in IIS for asp.net local website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727858/permissions-in-iis-for-asp-net-local-website)